# Merge syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make use of merge syntax but its not working

Please help me with this

```
create table tgt(id int,name varchar(10),age int)
insert into tgt values(1,'x',21),(2,'y',22),(3,'z',23)

create table src(id int,name varchar(10),age int)
insert into src values(1,'x1',24),(2,'x2',27),(4,'y1',27),(5,'z1',29),(3,'z',23)

merge tgt t using src s 
on t.id=s.id 
when matched then update src s
    set s.id=t.id,
    s.name=t.name,
    s.age=t.age
when not matched then
insert(id,name,age) values(s.id,s.name,s.age);
```

Error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'src'.
```

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? If yes, please consider of accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're confused with source & target. No table name is needed after `when matched then update` and make sure you're updating `target` table instead of `source` table.

Try this codes:

```
create table tgt(id int,name varchar(10),age int)
insert into tgt values(1,'x',21),(2,'y',22),(3,'z',23)

create table src(id int,name varchar(10),age int)
insert into src values(1,'x1',24),(2,'x2',27),(4,'y1',27),(5,'z1',29),(3,'z',23)

merge tgt t using src s 
on t.id=s.id 
when matched then 
    update 
    set t.id=s.id,
    t.name=s.name,
    t.age=s.age
when not matched then
    insert(id,name,age) values(s.id,s.name,s.age);
```